# Surface plot on bokeh wrapped in js shows blank

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, bokeh

I am trying to adapt the code found here [Bokeh JS wrapping interactive graph](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/wrapping.html)

I copied the code and commented out the data generating the sin waves and instead generated some data.  The html output is totally blank but I get no error messages.  Below is my bit of code that I adapted to test:

```
weeks=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
times=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

x_values = []
y_values = []
z_values = []

for week in weeks:
  for time in times:
    x_values.append(times)
    y_values.append(weeks)
    z_values.append(time*week)


source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x_values, y=y_values, z=z_values, color=z_values))


surface = Surface3d(x="Hour", y="Week", z="Number of Customers", color="color", data_source=source)

output_file("test_my_plot.html")
show(surface)
```

I read a bit about Mayavi, but it looks like it isn't interactive.  I also need it to be a single contained file so I can send it to others to open in a browser.  Any suggestions to fix my code or use another module would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I also found that just changing trivial pieces of the source code, like extending the range or changing the step of the x, y values also generates a blank plot...